# connection issue with PAn1026

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, embedded, uart

I am working on a project which sends data through bluetooth to an android device for which the controller is ADUCM360(Analog Devices) Bluetooth module is PAN1026(Panasonic).I am using SPP profile to send data.

I wrote a simple application code with the required commands and succeeded in discovering the PAN1026 module on my mobile(HTC one_M8).But when i try to connect (controller is the initiator),connection does not establish. I used TCU_SPP_CONNECT_REQ  command and tried to see the responses and I recieved TCU_MNG_CONNECTION_STATUS_EVENT in which status is always 0x80 (Page Timer-out) or 0x81 (Local device Connection Reject) and the connection status is always 0x02(Connection Failure).TCU_SPP_CONNECT_EVENT in which the status is always 0xD3(SPP connection failure).  PLease suggest me how do I fix this connection issue.

Here are the commands used (same sequence).

TCU_HCI_RESET_REQ

TCU_HCI_WRITE_BD_ADDR_REQ

TCU_HCI_SET_MODE_REQ

TCU_MNG_INIT_REQ

TCU_MNG_STANDARD_HCI_SET_REQ_Write_Class_of_Device

TCU_MNG_SET_SCAN_REQ

TCU_SPP_SETUP_REQ

TCU_SPP_CONNECT_REQ

TCU_SPP_DATA_TRANSFER_REQ